Why does my regex expression match when there's a newline after the target string, but not otherwise?
Example: https://regex101.com/r/ulzS4i/1
I have this regex:
^(?:[^a]|a[^b]|ab[^c])*$

It's designed to match all strings that don't contain abc without using negative lookaheads (as my dependency doesn't support that feature).
For the most part it works, except for the string cab: it fails to match cab and bca, but it matches them if I put a newline (or any other character) after. Why is this happening, and how can I fix my regex?
I'm using the Python regex flavor.

In the real validation, are there any other constraints you can pre-validate (e.g. fixed length, or that length is a multiple of 3)?

There are exactly two ways in which an a can be matched by this regex: if it is followed by a non-b, or if it is followed by b and then a non-c.  Both of your failing cases require at least one more character (not necessarily a newline) to fulfill that final non-whatever match.  One possible fix: add two more alternatives to your group, a$ and ab$.

There are other issues with the questioner's original regex.  E.g. it doesn't match "a".  It's an interesting challenge, though!

@MatthewFlaschen unfortunately not -- for more context, I'm working with constrained generation in LLMs, so the output could technically be arbitrary. The constrained generation libraries with regex all seem to not support negative lookaheads (which would make the problem very simple!)

@jasonharper I think you should post that as an answer.  I can't think of a flaw yet.

What exactly is the tool or programming language you're using? You say it's "the Python regex flavor", but Python regex does support negative lookahead patterns. Please clarify what your actual platform/dependency is so we can offer the best possible help.

Your regex is not correct, that is why. The correct regex to match a string that does not contain abc is ^([^a]|a(a|ba)*([^ab]|b[^ac]))*(a(a|ba)*b?)?$ - see this demo. (I added \n to the negated character classes so that the regex101 test against a single multiline string could pass.)

Can you evaluate capture groups in the tool? This kind of task usually can easily be solved by use of The Trick. Search for ^abc$|(.+) and if the first capture group is set you got a match... > The trick is that we match what we don't want on the left side of the alternation (the |), then we capture what we do want on the right side.

According to your question, 
You want a regex to find string which does not contains the abc substring only.
So, using negative lookaheads it's simple and regex as follows: https://regex101.com/r/S6RGav/1
^(?!.*abc).*

But, you don't want to use negative lookaheads, because it's not useful every where, like safari browser.
So, why not use it's Positive Lookaheads: https://regex101.com/r/6bHJLC/1
^(?:.*abc).*

During regex matching if it return true, then that string contains substring abc. Otherwise, it's not contains substring abc.
